# How to change Time Format in VB.NET from 24 to 12?

Tags: vb.net, time, format

I am using these codes for displaying time in VB.NET
it shows up in 24 hours format besides i need it in 12 hours format

```
System.DateTime.Now.Hour
System.DateTime.Now.Minute
System.DateTime.Now.Second
```

example:

```
14:12:42
```

I need it as :

```
02:12:42
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx). For example:

```
String.Format("{0:T}", System.DateTime.Now)           //02:12:42 PM
String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}", System.DateTime.Now)    //02:12:42
String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", System.DateTime.Now) //02:12:42 PM
```

Also, [this](http://idunno.org/archive/2004/07/14/122.aspx) website to be very helpful in summarizing the various ways you can use String.Format. Keep in mind the culture can make a difference on non-custom formats. The first example above using `T` (Long Time format) works on my US-based PC just fine. But if you say:

```
String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _
              "{0:T}", System.DateTime.Now)
```

You end up with 14:12:42. The latter two examples are custom formats and are not affected by culture.

Answer (score 0):

Use the appropriate format string for display.

```
string formatted = myDateTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

I have used a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) in this case.

Comment: Uppercase MM will return the month.

Answer (score 0):

When using DateTime objects you can actually use the ToString() method and set your format inside it.

```
string currentTime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Check this msdn article out for more clarity:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1-Use regex to get first two characters of that string ie from 23:11:59 get 23

2-convert this number to integer type

3-now check it if it is not greater than 12 and if it is subtract 12 from it and by using string.replace replace the old value.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
  Dim CurTime As String
  CurTime = TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
```